Intermittent: Angular MSAL 2: BrowserAuthError: state_interaction_type_mismatch
I have following versions of msal library.
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.1.0", 
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.21.0", 
"@angular/common": "13.1.3",
I am using loginPopup method to login.
Locally It is working fine all times.
But on server:
Sometimes it is working fine.
And sometimes it throws following error in popup console and stops login flow in between:
msal.js.browser@2.39.0 : Info - handleRedirectPromise was unable to extract state due to: BrowserAuthError: state_interaction_type_mismatch: Hash contains state but the interaction type does not match the caller.
I checked interaction type in configuration, it is popup only.
Please help on this. If you know when this error generates then also let me know.
